# Deploy Django App wih Dockerfile in Render

Tags: django, docker, dockerfile, django-deployment, render.com

I'm trying to deploy Django application with Dockerfile in **Render.com**.

I have added the below codes in ***Dockerfile*** -

```
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.10-slim-buster

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir -p /code

WORKDIR /code

#install the linux packages, since these are the dependencies of some python packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libpq-dev \
    gcc \
    cron \
    wkhtmltopdf \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* !

COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt

RUN set -ex && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    rm -rf /root/.cache/

COPY . /code
```

And added the below codes in ***render.toml***,

```
[deploy]
startCommand = "sh /code/release.sh"
```

And, added the below in ***release.sh***,

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

I have created all the above files in project's root directory.
But, after building, it's not run/execute the ***release.sh***.
What's the proper way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Keith in the Render support community discussion - [Deploy Django App with Dockerfile](https://community.render.com/t/deploy-django-app-wih-dockerfile/12121), the `release.sh` script won't run automatically in the `render.toml` file, so update your Dockerfile and set your `release.sh` as a CMD command in the Dockerfile like shown:

```
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.10-slim-buster

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir -p /code

WORKDIR /code

#install the linux packages, since these are the dependencies of some python packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libpq-dev \
    gcc \
    cron \
    wkhtmltopdf \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* !

COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt

RUN set -ex && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    rm -rf /root/.cache/

COPY . /code
#Add the following lines to make the release.sh script executable to run your script
RUN chmod +x /code/release.sh
CMD ["/code/release.sh"]
```

Also ensure that your PostgresSQL database is setup and the appropriate environment variables (HOST, DBNAME, etc...) are defined correctly in your web service.

I had a similar issue deploying a Django docker app on Render and applied the above fix to deploy successfully, so hope this is useful and helps others in the future too.